# How old are Nokia maps?

Tags: here-api

I am using javascript API to show client assets on a Nokia MAP.  The whole Nokia map package is excellent and I have managed to enhance the interface pretty well using the various features available.   The problem I have is with the fact that certain assets (buildings) in North Africa are missing when you zoom in onto the area.  These assets have been there for the past 4 years.  Is this because the maps are old? If so, is there a plan for them to be updated?

Thanks

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Nokia HERE is still being developed, [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_%28Nokia%29) the wikipedia article on it. Is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Making updates to both the satellite imagery and the street maps themselves is a continuing and ongoing task. A recent announcement on [Nokia Conversations](http://conversations.nokia.com/2013/06/27/14-million-kilometers-of-new-aerial-images/) stated that *"better-resolution images covering 90% of global landmass will be available later this year"*, similarly [another post](http://conversations.nokia.com/2013/06/20/celebrating-gold-standard-maps/) noted that greater detail on the updated street maps was now available in various countries (for example in Tunisia) as part of a rolling program. You may be able to get an answer about a specific location by asking a question comment on the blog.

Alternatively, if a specific place or building is missing from the maps, there are two ways you could help to speed up the process of amending the data.

1. If you are a **business owner** and you want your business to be placed on the maps, go to  http://here.com/primeplaces,  select location using the widget and fill in the form: http://here.com/primeplaces/place/create - there is also a bulk load facility http://here.com/primeplaces/batch/upload . Note that whilst in theory anyone could add a place, the business owner will need to confirm and verify the details (such as opening times) before they will be displayed - this stops fraudulent entries being added.
2. If you wish to alter street maps directly, then you can try adding information using the [HERE Map creator](http://here.com/mapcreator/) - this allows you to update community maps which are later passed into the main core data set. Not all countries are open for editing, if you would like to report a change to a country not yet open for editing, open the Map Creator and navigate to the position you would like to add an object or report a change. Then right-click to open the context menu and left-click on *"Report map changes"*. Select the appropriate type of change and provide as much detail as you can.

Answer (score -1):

I am working on this in a big company, so it still working where the documentation site 
Click [here](https://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.0/symbols/nokia.html)!
This works with [reference links][blog] as well.

Comment: How does this relate to whether the mapping data is up to date?

Comment: Ok, I will b more accurate, I am working in a fleet company, and all time trucks send waypoints to the server where up to date data are stored. Please refer also to this link http://www.mobileburn.com/20626/news/nokia-maps-get-more-up-to-date-information-thanks-to-fedex-and-ups. Please remove your negative qualification